# Computing a natural sort value to store in DB for string sorting

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

Here are some examples of strings (mainly addresses):

```
12
20
43-B
43-C
123
2500
```

Now I put those in what I consider the "correct" order. If I were to have these values in a column in a DB table and return those in a MySQL search, I would get:

```
12
123
20
2500
43-B
43-C
```

Obviously that's incorrect -- `20` is not greater than `123`.

It's pretty easy to figure this out if I can guarantee that the value consists of purely integers, but when you throw in `43-B` and `43-C` (or even `12A` or whatever), then we start having problems. However, I can't simply strip out the numbers! I'm not entirely sure what it represents at this point, but I do have values such as `40W1`.

Personally, I'd sort that under 40 rather than 4000, but it's kind of a very rare edge case so I'm not too worried about that particular example. I **do** need to keep the letters in mind, though, because `40B` would come before `40C` -- but I would also expect `40-B` to come before `40C`. Tricky, right? I know.

I am willing to assume only alpha-numeric characters, though (i.e. strip the `-` from the string).

What I want to do is convert that string into a series of numbers that are definitely sortable.

For instance, `43-B` might turn into something like `10000031205` (padded) and gets stored in the database along with the rest of the row. When I do a search for my addresses, I can now sort by the sort column, and I get everything in order!

Things I cannot do:

- Compare them directly at run time
- Do this search in MySQL (the value needs to be calculated on a row by row basis)
- Use sort/asort/ksort or any sorting function in PHP

I need a value that can be stored in my database or search index upon which I can sort later!

Unfortunately, all of my attempts thus far have failed to produce the results I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: So, you essentially need a `natsort` of `preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9]/i','',$input)` (the resulting outcome would be this I mean, you state it cannot be handled like this)?

Comment: Correct. The result set is coming from a search index (elasticsearch), and it contains more than just the numbers I'm searching for. I need to be able to sort by a value and get the rest of the data in a natural sort order. If I needed just the numbers, your way would work, though! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't claim it to be the most efficient format, but it would work. I assume no negative numbers.

I padded to 5 digits, but the pad needs to be bigger than the largest number of digits in a numeric sequence.

```
$input = '43-B1';
$nat = preg_replace_callback('#\d+#', function($m) {
    return str_pad($m[0], 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}, $input);
echo $nat;
```

demo
http://codepad.viper-7.com/kefb4L

Answer (score 1):

I would go with 2 sort columns `sortNumber int, sortText varchar`, store in the first column `intval($string);` if you use PHP, `CAST(column as UNSIGNED)` in sql, in the other column the letters *without* any symbols (result of one `preg_replace(array('/^-?[0-9]+/','/[^A-Z0-9]/i'),'',$input)` run (I don't know an SQL way..), and `SORT BY sortNumber, sortText`. If you need floats taken in consideration it becomes a bit more elaborate, but not much.

Comment: Thanks! This would have worked well, I think, if I had changed the DB but fortunately another user came up with a solution that didn't require adjusting the DB.

Comment: If you don't care about `43-B` & `43C` sorting, sure ;) No worries. (try `insert into cmp values ('12'), ('123'), ('20'), ('2500'), ('43C'), ('43-B'),  ('4000'), ('40w1');`)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
preg_match('(\d*)[^a-zA-Z0-9]*(.*)', $houseNumber, $matches);
$sortable = sprintf("%08d%s", $matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Comment: This was close but I still wound up with results out of order. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table cmp ( a varchar(255));

insert into cmp values ('12'), ('123'), ('20'), ('2500'), ('43-B'), ('43-C'), 
('4000'), ('40w1');

select a, lpad(cast(a as unsigned), 20, 0) from cmp 
order by lpad(cast(a as unsigned), 20, 0);

+------+----------------------------------+
| a    | lpad(cast(a as unsigned), 20, 0) |
+------+----------------------------------+
| 12   | 00000000000000000012             |
| 20   | 00000000000000000020             |
| 40w1 | 00000000000000000040             |
| 43-B | 00000000000000000043             |
| 43-C | 00000000000000000043             |
| 123  | 00000000000000000123             |
| 2500 | 00000000000000002500             |
| 4000 | 00000000000000004000             |
+------+----------------------------------+
8 rows in set, 6 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

You can use an example like this to remove any non-number,
and sort naturally.

The warning is not really a show stopper,
consider you are trying to sort numerically from a string column.

Comment: This was probably my next step if I couldn't come up with a non-DB-altering solution. Fortunately, another user came up with a solution that didn't require adding a new DB table. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to save the numeric value in a separate column? If these are addresses, it might be reasonable. And performance would be better than hashing or processing strings.